# Microsoft Project unable to connect to Team Services online

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio, microsoft-project

This is the error I get when I try to bring the latest work items into a blank MS project file that I just connected to Team Services online.

[image]

I have got this error with MS Project 2013 and 2016 as well. In both cases I create a new project and connect to my project on its url: http://XXXX.visualstudio.com.

This is already authenticated and added to my list of servers. Even then, when I try to click on the button to get work items, I get this error above.

**EDIT**
My current environment consists of both VS 2013 Ult. and 2015 Enterprise along with MS Project 2016.

Comment: Which Team Explorer version are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Project on the desktop. I am not using Team explorer.

Comment: You must have team explorer or visual studio installed to access TFS. Have you tried repairing that installation?

Comment: I have VS 2015 Enterprise edition. Do I still need Team Explorer? In fact I was able to connect earlier and upload all the tasks. Now that I have made some edits online, I want to refresh my MS Project file with those updates.